# Complex SQL statement forum topic listing

Tags: sql

I've been attempting this for several hours with no luck, wondered if some SQL expert could put me out of my misery.

The statement is for a main forum page that lists all the topics, ordered by the last posted in. I have two tables FORUM_TOPICS and FORUM_REPLIES

FORUM_TOPICS has fields id, name, date
FORUM_REPLIES has id, topic_id, name, date, del

Here's what I've got so far, some lines being psuedo code. I'm having a problem because I'm trying to order the entire forum_topics listing by the last date found in forum_replies. Hopefully you'll get what I'm trying to do;

```
SELECT ft.*, fr.date as lastpost_date 
FROM forum_topics ft 
LEFT JOIN forum_replies fr ON fr.topic_id=ft.id
WHERE (fr.del=0 or fr.account_id=5) <-- need these conditions 
ORDER BY fr.date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

This doesnt do what I want, any advice?

Comment: What does it do? What do you want it to do? The code is good, so presumably only the logic is wrong. Possibly the `left join` is confusing you?  Since no topics without replies will be returned from your query (because of the `where` clause) I'd guess that your `left join` is wrong. Or else you need something like `WHERE fr.id is null or fr.del = 0 or fr.account_id = 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subselect to get the latest activity in given topic:

```
SELECT ft.*, fr.lastpost_date
FROM forum_topics ft
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        fr.topic_id,
        MAX(fr.date) AS lastpost_date
    FROM forum_replies fr
    WHERE (fr.del = 0 OR fr.account_id = 5)
    GROUP BY fr.topic_id
) fr ON fr.topic_id = ft.id
ORDER BY fr.lastpost_date
LIMIT 20
```

The subquery filters posts that have been deleted and sent by ordinary users and lists the latest date for each topic. In order to list only topics that have replies, the join type is set to `INNER`.

Comment: Ah of course! Silly me. Giving it a whirl now, thanks

Comment: Depending on the meaning of `fr.del` and `fr.account_id` you might need to use an aggregate function on them or select them with another join or move the WHERE clause to the subquery.

Comment: There seems to be a topic showing up twice in the listing, I think its one where the fr.del comes in. del is just posts that are flagged deleted, they only show if account_id=5 basically (admin). Also, should there be fr. references inside that subselect?

Comment: In that case the `WHERE` clause should probably be in the subquery, so you get each topic only once. Also the join type should be `INNER` unless you want topics without replies listed.

Comment: thank you for your help. It lists them correctly now, but seem unable to pull the correct fr.author relative to the last post. Will keep trying

Comment: I think I had to solve a similar problem some time ago, I just can't remember how I did it. If you can make assumptions about monotonicity of the id numbers of the posts, you can use something like `MAX(fr.id)` in the subquery. (I'm not sure if this matters in your case but if a transaction at the time of posting a message takes a very long time to complete, it could affect the date.)